# What are the available options we have to migrate a Web Access database from sharepoint 2010 to sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2010, migration, access, excel-web-access-webpart

I am working on an existing sharepoint on-premises 2010, and our aim is to migrate this on-premises 2010 to sharepoint online. now i checked the sites and they contain regular document libraries and lists, which should be smoothly get migrated using any third party tool or using the sharepoint online migration tool.

but i found a sub-site which contain something similar to an Access database, as follow:-

1. I found this document library:-
   [image]
2. When i click on it, i thought i will get list of documents, but i got those items and a database, as follow:-

[image]

3. Also when i access the home page of the site i got this online database, as follow:-

[image]

Now i have not worked on sharepoint 2010, so i am not sure what does the above represent? is it an access database published to a sharepoint 2010 site? also most importantly, can we migrate this database to sharepoint online? if we can then can anyone adivce on the approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access web apps no longer run in SharePoint online and migrating this database will not be possible. If the business still requires this functionality, you need to look into other options, for example Power Apps as the user interface for data stored in SharePoint.

Edit: Microsoft announced the death of Access web apps for SharePoint online in March 2017.  From June 2017, it was no longer possible to create new Access web apps and existing Access web apps were given until April 2018 to be ported to other platforms.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-Retirement-Blog/Updating-the-Access-Services-in-SharePoint-Roadmap/ba-p/57148

The outcry in the user community still resounds.

Don't shoot the messenger. This is the answer to your question and should be marked as such, whether you like it or not.

Comment: thanks for the reply, so you mean what i have is a Access web apps? and  i found some videos and documents which mentioned that we can still create web access in SP online such as this video @ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3OyPRa9_NWY..

Comment: can you advice on my above comment ? thanks

Comment: Yeah, well, that's a bit outdated. A lot can happen in 4 years. I edited my answer to provide more detail.

Comment: so you mean now we can not create web access projects inside sharepoint online? anyway i can not see your edit.

Comment: Correct. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-Retirement-Blog/Updating-the-Access-Services-in-SharePoint-Roadmap/ba-p/57148

Comment: ok i see, so now when we say that power-app is the replacement for the Access web apps, does this allow us to automatically convert an Access web app to power apps? or this conversion/migration need to be done manually?

Comment: Nothing automatic about migrating to PowerApps, unfortunately. It's a long and steep learning curve and nobody will do the conversion for free. In fact, there will be no conversion. You will have to totally re-create the whole application from scratch. Again, don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: ok thanks for the great info ...